# Bootstrap React tabs are not showing title/Tab name, what is the issue?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {Tab, Tabs, TabList, TabPanel} from 'react-bootstrap-tabs';

const tabsInstance = (
  <Tabs defaultActiveKey={2} id="uncontrolled-tab-example" bsStyle="pils">
    <Tab eventKey={1} title="Tab 1" >
    Tab 1 content
    </Tab>

    <Tab eventKey={2} title="Tab 2">
    Tab 2 content
    </Tab>

    <Tab eventKey={3} title="Tab 3">Tab 3 content</Tab>
  </Tabs>
);

class ProfileTab extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

  }
  render(){
    return (
      <section>
         <div className="container-fluid profile_section_container">
            {tabsInstance}
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }

}

export default ProfileTab;
```

The tab title is not showing tabs are working fine and clickable but not showing

Bootstrap React tabs are not showing title/Tab name, what is the issue ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use label instead.

```
<Tab eventKey={1} title="Tab 1" label="Tab 1">
Tab 1 content
</Tab>

<Tab eventKey={2} title="Tab 2" Label="Tab 2">
Tab 2 content
</Tab>

<Tab eventKey={3} title="Tab 3" Label="Tab 3">Tab 3 content</Tab>
```

);

Comment: Yes, with assigning a Label thing is working

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're not putting any custom components in the hierarchy between Tabs and it's Tab children. React Bootstrap is looking for "title" on the direct descendants of Tabs.

**Doesn't work:**

```
<Tabs>
    <CustomComponent>
      <Tab title="Your Title">...</Tab>
    </CustomComponent>
</Tab>
```

**Works:**

```
<Tabs>
    <Tab title="Your Title">...</Tab>
</Tab>
```

See response here: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/2246#issuecomment-251266675

Answer (score 0):

```html
As Danny mentioned above using label it will visible.
here is another example.

`<Tabs
                id="portfolio-main-tab"
                activeKey={key}
                onSelect={(k) => setKey(k)}
                className="nav nav-tabs"
            >
                <Tab eventKey="home" title="Home" label="Home">
                    <div>Tab 1</div>
                </Tab>
                <Tab eventKey="profile" title="Profile" label="Profile">
                    <div>Profile</div>
                </Tab>
            </Tabs>`
```